# How should we implement std::error_code compatible API?

Tags: c++, error-handling, c++11

Assuming we are writing a library and that we want to provide fine grain control over error and exceptions:

```
void foo();
void foo(std::error_code&);
```

Sould we implement `foo()` as throwing a [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) and let `foo(std::error_code&)` catch all exception and extract the error_code.

Or sould we implement `foo(std::error_code&)` as a never throwing function and throw a function in `foo()` depending on the presence of an error code?

Comment: Look at boost::asio for example. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/connect.html

Comment: I'd say it also depends on what `foo()` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost` library works with exceptions and with `boost::system::error_code`, so, i think you can orientate on this library. For example [boost::asio::basic_stream_socket::connect](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/connect.html) has two versions

```
void connect(
    const endpoint_type & peer_endpoint);
```

> boost::system::system_error Thrown on failure.

```
boost::system::error_code connect(
    const endpoint_type & peer_endpoint,
    boost::system::error_code & ec);
```

> ec Set to indicate what error occurred, if any.

But it depends on what `foo` does, i think too.

Answer (score -4):

Less exceptions is always better, so you should use the second one.